# Script for analyzing millions of lines

Tags: python, performance, datetime, regex

I have files with over 100 million lines in each:

> ```
> ...
> 01-AUG-2012 02:29:44 important data
> 01-AUG-2012 02:29:44 important data
> 01-AUG-2012 02:36:02 important data
> some unimportant data
> blahblah (also unimportant data)
> some unimportant data
> 01-AUG-2012 02:40:15 important data
> some unimportant data
> ...
> ```

As you can see, there are important data (starting with date and time) and unimportant data.  Also in each second, there can be many lines of important data.

My goal is to count the number of "important data" in each second (or minute or hour...) and reformat date/time format. My script also lets me count data in each minute, hour etc using `options.dlen`:

> ```
> options.dlen = 10 takes YYYY-MM-DDD
> options.dlen = 13 takes YYYY-MM-DDD HH
> options.dlen = 16 takes YYYY-MM-DDD HH:MM
> options.dlen = 20 takes YYYY-MM-DDD HH:MM:SS
> ```

I have written the following script (this is the main part - I skip all the file openings, parameters etc).

```
DATA = {}

# search for DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS
# e.g. "01-JUL-2012 02:29:36 important data"
pattern = re.compile('^\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} important data')

DATA = defaultdict(int)
i = 0
f = open(options.infilename, 'r')
for line in f:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        if options.verbose:
            i += 1
            # print out every 1000 iterations
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print str(i) + '\r',

        # converts data date/time format to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format (but still keep it as datetime !)
        d = datetime.strptime( line [0:20], '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        # converts d, which is datetime to string again
        day_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        DATA [ str(day_string[0:int(options.dlen)]) ] += 1
f.close()
#L2 = sorted(DATA.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
#L2 = sorted(DATA.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
L2 = sorted(DATA.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

It takes about 3 hours to process over 100 million lines. Can you suggest performance improvements for this script?

Update: I have just used PyPy and the same task on the same server took 45 minutes.  I will try to add profile statistics.

Comment: Without proper profiling we can only guess where the bottleneck is. Create a smaller test file (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/head/) and run your script under [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Comment: You can use **Python** [**Multiprocessing**](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) to process the lines concurrently

Comment: Without knowing whether your program is CPU-bound or IO-bound, it's hard to say how to optimize this. You can tell with the `time(1)` command.

Comment: One way to quickly improve your script's time would be to trim down the number of lines it has to deal with - pipe your input file through something like `grep '^[0-9]'` before your script gets to it, so that you only process the lines that are important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1. Make a test case

The first thing to do is to establish the existence of the performance problem, so let's knock up some test data.

```
def make_test_file(filename, n, t, delta):
    """
    Write `n` lines of test data to `filename`, starting at `t` (a
    datetime object) and stepping by `delta` (a timedelta object) each
    line.
    """
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for _ in xrange(n):
            f.write(t.strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S ').upper())
            f.write('important data\n')
            t += delta

>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> make_test_file('data.txt', 10**5, datetime.now(), timedelta(seconds=1))
```

And then with the OP's code in the function `aggregate1(filename, dlen)`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:aggregate1('data.txt', 16), number = 1)
5.786283016204834
```

So on the real file (1000 times bigger) that would take an hour and a half on my machine (or longer, if the time complexity is worse than linear). So yes, there's a real performance problem.

### 2. Clean up the code

Let's try a bunch of obvious minor improvements and optimizations (mostly as suggested in other answers):

1. Convert `dlen` to an integer once (not every for every line).
2. Write `day_string[:dlen]` instead of `str(day_string[0:dlen])`.
3. Write `pattern.match(line)` instead of `re.match(pattern, line)`.
4. There's no need for `key = operator.itemgetter(0)` because the sort will proceed on the first element of the pair in any case.
5. Rename `DATA` as `count` and `day_string` with `s` (it's really a date-time string, not a day string).
6. Use `with` to ensure that the file is closed in the event of an error.
7. Import the name `strptime` so it doesn't have to be looked up for every line.

Let's try that:

```
def aggregate2(filename, dlen):
    strptime = datetime.datetime.strptime
    dlen = int(dlen)
    pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} important data')
    count = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if pattern.match(line):
                d = strptime(line[:20], '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
                s = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                count[s[:dlen]] += 1
    return sorted(count.iteritems())

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:aggregate2('data.txt', 10), number = 1)
5.200263977050781
```

A small improvement, 10% or so, but clean code makes the next step easier.

### 3. Profile

```
>>> import cProfile
>>> cProfile.run("aggregate2('data.txt', 10)")
         2700009 function calls in 6.262 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.262    6.262 <string>:1(<module>)
   100000    0.088    0.000    1.020    0.000 _strptime.py:27(_getlang)
   100000    2.098    0.000    4.033    0.000 _strptime.py:295(_strptime)
   100000    0.393    0.000    0.642    0.000 locale.py:339(normalize)
   100000    0.105    0.000    0.747    0.000 locale.py:407(_parse_localename)
   100000    0.119    0.000    0.933    0.000 locale.py:506(getlocale)
   100000    0.067    0.000    0.067    0.000 {_locale.setlocale}
   100000    0.515    0.000    4.548    0.000 {built-in method strptime}
   100000    0.079    0.000    0.079    0.000 {isinstance}
   200000    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 {len}
   100000    0.043    0.000    0.043    0.000 {method 'end' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
   300001    0.076    0.000    0.076    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
   100000    0.276    0.000    0.276    0.000 {method 'groupdict' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
   100000    0.090    0.000    0.090    0.000 {method 'index' of 'list' objects}
   100000    0.025    0.000    0.025    0.000 {method 'iterkeys' of 'dict' objects}
   100000    0.046    0.000    0.046    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
   200000    0.553    0.000    0.553    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
   100000    1.144    0.000    1.144    0.000 {method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects}
```

I've cut some of the output for clarity. It should be clear that the culprits are `strptime` (73% of runtime), `strftime` (18%), and `match` (9%). Everything else is either called by one of those, or negligible.

### 4. Pluck the low-hanging fruit

We can avoid calling *both* `strptime` and `strftime` if we recognize that the only things we are achieving by calling these two functions are (a) to translate the months from names (`AUG`) to numbers (`08`), and (b) to reorder the components into ISO standard order. So let's do that ourselves:

```
def aggregate3(filename, dlen):
    dlen = int(dlen)
    months = dict(JAN = '01', FEB = '02', MAR = '03', APR = '04',
                  MAY = '05', JUN = '06', JUL = '07', AUG = '08',
                  SEP = '09', OCT = '10', NOV = '11', DEC = '12')
    pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{2})-([A-Z]{3})-(\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) '
                         'important data')
    count = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            m = pattern.match(line)
            if m:
                s = '{3}-{0}-{1} {4}'.format(months[m.group(2)], *m.groups())
                count[s[:dlen]] += 1
    return sorted(count.iteritems())

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda:aggregate3('data.txt', 10), number = 1)
0.5073871612548828
```

There you go: a 90% speedup! That should get you down from three hours to 20 minutes or so. There are a few more things one might try (for example, doing the aggregations for all the different values of `dlen` in a single pass). But I think this is enough to be going on with.

Answer (score 4):

```
DATA = {}
```

Python convention is for ALL_CAPS to be reserved for constants

```
# search for DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS
# e.g. "01-JUL-2012 02:29:36 important data"
pattern = re.compile('^\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} important data')

DATA = defaultdict(int)
i = 0
f = open(options.infilename, 'r')
```

I recommend using `with` to make sure the file is closed

```
for line in f:
```

You should put this loop in a function. Code inside a function runs faster then code at the top level

```
    if re.match(pattern, line):
```

Do you really need a regular expression? From the file listing you gave maybe you should be checking `line[20:] == 'important data'`

Also, use `pattern.match(line)`, `re.match` works passing a precompiled pattern, but I've found that it has much worse performance.

```
        if options.verbose:
            i += 1
            # print out every 1000 iterations
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print str(i) + '\r',




        # converts data date/time format to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format (but still keep it as datetime !)
        d = datetime.strptime( line [0:20], '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        # converts d, which is datetime to string again
        day_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        DATA [ str(day_string[0:int(options.dlen)]) ] += 1
```

There's a good chance you  might be better off storing the datetime object rather then the string. On the other hand, is the file already in sorted order? In that case all you need to do is check whether the time string has changed, and you can avoid storing things in a dictionary

```
f.close()
#L2 = sorted(DATA.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
#L2 = sorted(DATA.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
L2 = sorted(DATA.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

If the incoming file is already sorted, you'll save a lot of time by maintaining that sort.

Comment: This code is in def main(): which is then run by   if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
Is that what you say about putting inside function ?

Comment: @przemol, yes that's what I mean by putting inside a function. If you've already done that: good.

Answer (score 3):

Use string operations instead of regular expression matching. RE uses a fully featured engine which is redundant in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ideas, none of them tested:

1. Use a quick test to skip lines that can't possibly match the format.

   ```
   if line[:2].isdigit():
   ```
2. Skip the regular expression entirely and let `strptime` raise an exception if the format isn't correct.
3. Skip `strptime` and `strftime` and use the original date string directly in your dictionary. Use a second step to convert the strings before you sort, or use a custom sort key and retain the original format.